# Jotform: Parse returned data issue

Tags: php, json, jotform

I'm trying to parse data returned by the Jotform API.

I'm successfully echoing the data but I'm also getting unnecessary additional lines of text.

My PHP code is:

include "JotForm.php";

```
$jotformAPI = new JotForm("myapikey");

$submissions = $jotformAPI->getFormSubmissions("myformid");
var_dump($submissions );

foreach ($submissions as $data) {
    $detail = $jotformAPI->getSubmission($data['id']);

    foreach ($detail as $d) {
        echo $d[1]['answer']['first'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

result of var_dump($submissions );

```
{
"responseCode": 200,
"message": "success",
"content": [{
    "id": "237955080346633702",
    "form_id": "31751954731962",
    "ip": "123.123.123.123",
    "created_at": "2013-06-25 03:38:00",
    "updated_at": "2013-06-27 04:58:00",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "new": "1",
    "answers": {
        "1": {
            "text": "Name",
            "type":"control_fullname",
            "answer": {
                "first": "LeBron",
                "last": "James"
            },
            "prettyFormat": "LeBron James"
        },
        "2": {
            "text": "Your Message",
            "type": "control_textarea",
            "answer":"¡Ay, caramba!"
        }
}],
```

}

And here is the result I'm getting:

```
1
0
0
0
C



0
LeBron
```

Comment: Please show us `var_export($detail);`  At first glance, it looks like you are accessing a string @ `$d[1]['answer']` but `$d[1]['answer']['first']` might not be a string.  This means php is trying to find the character (byte) that has an  "offset" of `first`, but, of course, offsets must be numeric, so php converts `first` to `0` and shows you the first character in the string. ...just a hunch. Maybe the blank lines are where php is erroring out Do you have any errors in your error log?

Comment: Please always include some sample input and your exact desired output from the sample data.

Comment: added the var_dump result @mickmackusa. desired result is "LeBron"

Comment: Sorry, may I see `$submissions` please?  Do you only what to access the first subarray and get 1 value total?  Or are you wanting to access the `['answer']['first']` value from every subarray in the data?  I need to know all of the response data so that I can advice the best approach.

Comment: Yes, every subarray. Suppose $submissions returns 20 entries, the hope is that it returns 20 last names. Next comment var_dump for $detail. I think I included var_dump of $detail['answer'] in the question.

Comment: 'answers' => 
    array (size=65)
      1 => 
        array (size=7)
          'answer' => 
            array (size=2)
          'first' => string 'LeBron' (length=6)
          'last' => string 'James' (length=5)     2 => ....

'answers' => 
    array (size=65)
      1 => 
        array (size=7)
          'answer' => 
            array (size=2)
          'first' => string 'Stephen' (length=7)
          'last' => string 'Curry' (length=5)
      2 => ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to repair your invalid json string...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Qa7FI))

```
$json = '{
"responseCode": 200,
"message": "success",
"content": [{
    "id": "237955080346633702",
    "form_id": "31751954731962",
    "ip": "123.123.123.123",
    "created_at": "2013-06-25 03:38:00",
    "updated_at": "2013-06-27 04:58:00",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "new": "1",
    "answers": {
        "1": {
            "text": "Name",
            "type":"control_fullname",
            "answer": {
                "first": "LeBron",
                "last": "James"
            },
            "prettyFormat": "LeBron James"
        },
        "2": {
            "text": "Your Message",
            "type": "control_textarea",
            "answer":"¡Ay, caramba!"
        }
}}]
}';
foreach (json_decode($json, true)['content'] as $set) {
    echo "{$set['answers'][1]['answer']['first']} {$set['answers'][1]['answer']['last']}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
LeBron James
```

---

I'm a little fuzzy on the action of the jot functions, but maybe it's supposed to be like this:

```
foreach ($submissions as $data) {
    $detail = $jotformAPI->getSubmission($data['id']);
    echo $detail['answers'][1]['answer']['first'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I have to guess if this works because I don't have `$submissions` data to test with.  With sample input data, I may be able to devise a more clever approach.

Comment: it returned a lot of rows after the first name. Below is an example response for $jotformAPI->getSubmission($data['id'])

{
    "responseCode": 200,
    "content": [{
        "id": "237955080346633702",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "new": "1",
        "answers": {
            "3": {
                "text": "Name",
                "type":"control_fullname",
                "answer": {
                    "first": "Bart",
                    "last": "Simpson"
                },
                "prettyFormat": "Bart Simpson"
            },
    }],
}

Comment: I can't get started without receiving a valid json string or the `var_export($submissions)` data that I've requested.  Notice that I keep saying "var_export()".  or if providing a json string, don't pretty print, just echo it out.

Comment: aha. the above is actually the response for $jotformAPI->getFormSubmissions("FORM ID");
as seen in their API doc: https://api.jotform.com/docs/#form-id-submissions

Comment: When posting a question on StackOverflow, it is important that you provide the sample input and your EXACT desired output from that input.

Comment: I've edited the question to include var_dump($submissions)

Comment: your last update did it! a million thanks. saved my day.